# My method is outputting an entire array instead of an integer from within that array

Tags: ruby, tic-tac-toe

I am creating a tic tac toe game where I would like the computer to go in strategic spots based on the available winning combos on the board. For some reason, the `computer_index` method works until `turn_count == 4`, where it outputs the entire `WIN_COMBINATIONS` array instead of just one value. Understandably, this creates an error in the `valid_move?` method. The relevant error and code are as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from tictactoe.rb:12:in `<main>'
    2: from /Users/irosen419/Flatiron/code/tictactoe/tic_tac_toe.rb:201:in `play'
    1: from /Users/irosen419/Flatiron/code/tictactoe/tic_tac_toe.rb:117:in `comp_turn'
/Users/irosen419/Flatiron/code/tictactoe/tic_tac_toe.rb:40:in `valid_move?': undefined method `between?' for #<Array:0x00007fbe650d8268> (NoMethodError)
```

```rb
WIN_COMBINATIONS = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8]]

def valid_move?(index)
  index.between?(0,8) && !position_taken?(index)
end

def computer_index
  if turn_count == 0
    CORNERS.sample
  elsif turn_count == 2
    CORNERS.sample
  elsif turn_count == 4 || turn_count == 6
    WIN_COMBINATIONS.each do |combo|
      if @board[combo[0]] == "X" && @board[combo[1]] == "X"
          @board[combo[2]]
      elsif @board[combo[1]] == "X" && @board[combo[2]] == "X"
        @board[combo[0]]
      elsif @board[combo[0]] == "X" && @board[combo[2]] == "X"
        @board[combo[1]]
      elsif @board[combo[0]] == "O" && @board[combo[1]] == "O"
          @board[combo[2]]
      elsif @board[combo[1]] == "O" && @board[combo[2]] == "O"
        @board[combo[0]]
      elsif @board[combo[0]] == "O" && @board[combo[2]] == "O"
        @board[combo[1]]
      else
        CORNERS.sample
      end
    end
  else
    @board.each do |space|
      if space == " "
        space
      end
    end
  end
end

def comp_turn
  index = computer_index
  if valid_move?(index)
    move(index, current_player)
    display_board
  else
    comp_turn
  end
end

def turn_count
  count = 0
  @board.each do |space|
    if space == "X" || space == "O"
      count +=1
    end
  end
  count
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing `return` statements :

```rb
def computer_index
  if turn_count == 0
    CORNERS.sample
  elsif turn_count == 2
    CORNERS.sample
  elsif turn_count == 4 || turn_count == 6
    WIN_COMBINATIONS.each do |combo|
      if @board[combo[0]] == "X" && @board[combo[1]] == "X"
        return @board[combo[2]]
      elsif @board[combo[1]] == "X" && @board[combo[2]] == "X"
        return @board[combo[0]]
      elsif @board[combo[0]] == "X" && @board[combo[2]] == "X"
        return @board[combo[1]]
      elsif @board[combo[0]] == "O" && @board[combo[1]] == "O"
        return @board[combo[2]]
      elsif @board[combo[1]] == "O" && @board[combo[2]] == "O"
        return @board[combo[0]]
      elsif @board[combo[0]] == "O" && @board[combo[2]] == "O"
        return @board[combo[1]]
      else
        return CORNERS.sample
      end
    end
  else
    @board.each do |space|
      if space == " "
        space
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I was under the impression that Ruby has implicit return. Without "return," the method still seems to work for turn_count 0 and 2. With the "return," I receive a new error which makes even less sense to me in this context ...```tic_tac_toe.rb:39:in `between?': comparison of String with 0 failed (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: You are right ruby has implicit return for the last evaluated expression. But `#each` returns the collection you iterated on.

Comment: And for you error message : seems like `@board[combo[2]]` returns a string instead of a number.

Comment: Correct. That fixed the immediate problem. Thank you!